Inequality in open set

See picture
If the green (bigger) circle is a unit sphere, and tangents on the smaller circle are symmetric with line containing the origin, is it possible to prove that there is a constant $A$ such that for every point $x$ in red area $|x-\zeta|<A(1-|x|)$, where $\zeta$ is the point from the unit sphere( south pole in the picture)
I tried using cosines low on triangle with vertices 0,x $\zeta$ but didn't succeed.
This is part of a bigger theorem, so I didn't put all of it. I appreciate any help

Here is a long hint:
Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{1-|x|}{|x-\zeta|}$, $x \in$ red except $\zeta$. By compactness, we only investigate $x$ near $\zeta$.
Now consider only $x$ on the right line, call the center $O$, draw $OH$ perpendicular to the right line, $H$ on the right line. Call $\beta$ the angle $\zeta OH$, $\alpha$ the angle $xOH$ then $f(x)$ can be expressed as $\frac{\cos\alpha - \cos \beta}{sin(\beta-\alpha)}$ which converges to some positive constant as $x$ runs to $\zeta$ on the right line ($\alpha \uparrow \beta$).
From above observation, you can now let $x$ be outside  the right line, but still close to $\zeta$. Draw a circle with center $O$, radius $Ox = |x|$. It cuts the right line at $x' = x'(x)$ (depends on $x$) and try to lower bound $f(x)$ based on $f(x')$ (i.e., $f(x) \geq c f(x')$ where $c >0$ is some constant).
If you are more careful, I believe you can even compute exactly what $A$ is.
